# Java regex to prevent match for specific keywords

Tags: java, regex

I have been exploring negative look ahead and negative look behind. But they don't seem to do what I want.

Say I have a sentence "word1 word2 word3 word4", I need a regex that **refuse** a match if word3 or word7 exist in that sentence. In another word `matcher.find()` should be `false`. How do I do that?

Ideally I want the captured sentence to be as relaxed as possible `.*` however I only able to prevent a match if I tighten captured sentence, see `(\\w{4}\\d{1}\\s.*)` section below which ends up as `//Result: Nothing`

```
    String contents = null;
    contents = "word1 word2 word3 word4";
    m = Pattern.compile("(?i)(.*)").matcher(contents);
    //Result: word1 word2 word3 word4

    m = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?!.*(word3))(.*)").matcher(contents);
    //Result: ord3 word4

    m = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?!.*(word3))(\\w{4}\\d{1}\\s.*)").matcher(contents);
    //Result: Nothing

    m = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?<!(word3))(.*)").matcher(contents);
    //Result: word1 word2 word3 word4

    m = Pattern.compile("(?i)(.*)(?<!(word3))").matcher(contents);
    //Result: word1 word2 word3 word4

    m = Pattern.compile("(?i)(.*)(?<!(word4))").matcher(contents);
    //Result: word1 word2 word3 word
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with negative blockheads, but two general pieces of advice: Regex doesn't look like the right tool for this to me, and when you do really need to use regex I can recommend this site to debug: https://regex101.com/

Comment: What about checking if the word exists in the sentence first and then, if it doesn't, apply the matcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?!.*(word1|word2|word3|word4|word5|word6|word7)).*$");
Matcher matcher = patter.matcher(" word1");
System.out.println(matcher.find());
```

This can be simplified depending on patterns in those words, e.g.:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?!.*(word[1-7])).*$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(" word8");
boolean b = m.find();
```

Comment: Thank you @grzegorz-górkiewicz realized my mistake now. I was missing the ^... $